# Gmail profile picture not on emails

Tags: gmail, photos, profile

My desired Google profile picture appears on my Gmail account and I've checked both the gear in top right corner and https://plus.google.com/s and it is in both places, but when I send an email and the message is accessed from the inbox, there is no photo.

What am I missing?  My other Gmail account works fine, but I don't know what is different.

Comment: How long did you wait? It might take a while to update the entire Google network.

Answer (score 1):

This drove me crazy for the past hour, but I think I just figured it out---it seems that your profile image will not display to the address you are sending the email to until they send you an email back.